# Switching to iTerm window does not have cursor active

Tags: macos, iterm2

I have an iTerm2 running on fullscreen mode, but whenever I switch to it either by using  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> or by swiping between windows, the cursor is not active and it requires clicking on the window to make it active

[image: window switching action but cursor not active]

What configuration do I need to change for iTerm to be active when switching to it?

iTerm 2 Build 3.4.16

macOS Montery 12.5.1 (21G83)